# Am I on the right track (ASPX, ascx, design)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

I have several webpages, each of these pages are more or less the same. Each of them have a employee section at the top. Next section is the customer section, and section after is previous orders. These two are not strictly necessary on all pages. Last section is comments (blogging).

I started out with 2 pages, no problem. I wrote the same (copy-paste) code for each page (give or take a couple of details). Sales gave(baited) this to the customer and the customer got hungry .. more more MORE... Now I have 10 pages with more or less the same code.

Now I was thinking can I reduce dev time by reusing the same "controls". So started doing some ascx (4), thinking I could reuse these 4 controls with each page (employee, customer, sales, blog).

I run into a little snatch and google tells me - "no no no that is not how you use ascx". An ascx is merely a new "`asp:label`" / "`asp:textbox`" with perhaps a little extra logic in.

Snatch being - I made a NewTest.aspx with each of the 4 controls in, but I'm not seeing the `asp:formview` / `asp:detailsview` etc from the controls. I can put "hello worlds" all around the formview, just before, just after - but not inside the `<formview></formview>`.

Where am I going wrong, what do I need to reconsider?

NewTest.aspx

```
    <table width="800">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <IIT:EmployeeRecord ID="test1" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
```

I use ObjectDataSource and pull the employee ID from Session. The Employee record - His name, a dropdown with his zipcodes(salesrep only) and a search field. Basicly a textbox(es) with a little extra logic.

All the underlying logic (BLLs, DALs, Models, etc) are precisely the same. Rest of the project compiles and runs precisely the same as before I started with the ascx's.

Edit: I'm trying hard to KSS this, if I can get EmployeeRecord to show, then I can copy-paste that idea.

Start in webconfig:

```
<pages>
<controls>
    <add tagPrefix="IIT" tagName="Comments" src="~/DynamicData/FieldTemplates/Comments.ascx" />
    <add tagPrefix="IIT" tagName="OrderRecord" src="~/DynamicData/FieldTemplates/OrderRecord.ascx" />
    <add tagPrefix="IIT" tagName="CustomerRecord" src="~/DynamicData/FieldTemplates/CustomerRecord.ascx" />
    <add tagPrefix="IIT" tagName="EmployeeRecord" src="~/DynamicData/FieldTemplates/EmployeeRecord.ascx" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

Intellisense can recognise EmployeeRecord and OrderRecord, but not Comments and CustomerRecord. *Edit: Intellisense now recognises them all.*

EmployeeRecord

```
<asp:formview ID="fv_empDetail" runat="server" datasourceID="ods_empDetail">
<itemtemplate>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Medarbejder:
        </td>
    <td>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbEmployeeName" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>' BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox>
</td></tr>
</table>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ods_empDetail" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetEmployee"
     TypeName="xxxxxx.EmployeeBLL">
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:SessionParameter Name="employee" DbType="String" SessionField="employee" />
     </SelectParameters>
 </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

(Any typos are for your pleasure only ;) , there are no typos in the real code)

Comment: sounds like you're definitely on the right track to me; 10 cut and paste forms (spiraling into 50 ... then 100 ... :D) would be a nightmare to maintain, and refactoring into common code is definitely a best practice.  however, i'm not sure how to tackle this without more information: is there any way you could create a demo project that demonstrates what you are talking about and provide the code? that would give us the ability to look and see specifically what the problems are rather than just trying to figure out how to reproduce it from the textual description. :) thanks!

Comment: If I might give you a little suggestion. Since you seem really committed about using architectural patterns, organizing your code, doing "the right stuff in the right place" etc, take a look at asp.net MVC for your presentation layer. It provides a more web-standard approach, testability, and much more. If you need more convincing, stackoverflow and the whole stack exchange network are built with asp.net Mvc :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MasterPage for your project. If you think that there are information for some common specific group of pages irresective of other groups, then use a nested master page for those specific groups of pages.

Using nested masterpages will keep your root masterpage light, and will serve for other pages too.

You can also follow the link for developing user control as given by @Umar or refer to the following:

[Create ASP.NET user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26db8ysc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[My User Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/myusercontrol.aspx)

Comment: The "My User Control" gave me a nudge in the right direction. Allow me to test a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a master page that contains all the information common to all pages and then only fill in the information that is page specific?

Comment: My previous question on SO gave me the advice of never putting that much logic into the masterpage. Idea sounds good though. I'll consider it.

Comment: @DoStuffZ - what kind of logic do you think would be in your master page?

Comment: @Charles Boyung - Good question, as little as I could get around with. Semi-static, layout defaults, and such.

Comment: @DoStuffZ - I don't see why any of that shouldn't go into the master page and its code behind. I checked out the other question you referenced and he wasn't really talking about no longer in the master page, he was just saying that the logic should be in the code behind file for the master page, which is good practice for Asp.Net in general - just about all logic should be in the .cs files, not the .aspx/.ascx/.master files

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem correctly, what you are trying to do is to place Web controls (custom or otherwise) within your own custom controls.

I think what you are trying to do is to create templated ASP.NET controls. Please see the article [How to: Create Templated ASP.NET User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

This will enable you to write something like the following in your ASPX/ASCX files.

```
<uc:TemplateTest runat="server">
  <MessageTemplate>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text='Foo!!' />
    <br />
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2" Text='Bar!!' />
    <hr />
  </MessageTemplate>
</uc:TemplateTest>
```

*NB: This example has been adapted from the article linked to above.*

Notice how two `asp:Label` tags exist inside the `MessageTemplate` element of the `uc:TemlpateTest`.